# How to analyze JS Literals/Identifiers using ESLint Custom Rules

Tags: javascript, eslint, static-analysis, eslintrc, typescript-eslint

I'll explain the scenario with an example.

Suppose I have following JS code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Department/GetAllUsers',
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    success: function (result) {
        //Some Code
    },
    error: function () {
        //Some Code
    }
});
```

And I want to restrict call to that action of the controller. So I have written following Custom ES Lint rule for this:

```
module.exports = {
    meta: {
        type: "problem",
        docs: {
            description: "Prohibited Method",
            category: "Method",
            recommended: true,
            url: ""
        },
        messages: {
            messageDefault: "This method is Prohibited to use"
        },
        fixable: "code",
        schema: [] // no options
    },
    create: function (context) {
        return {
            Literal(node) {
                var literalValue = node.value.toString();
                var cont = literalValue.split("/").filter(x => x.length > 1);
                {
                    if (cont[0] === 'Department' && cont[1] === 'GetAllUsers') {

                        context.report({
                            node: node,
                            messageId: "messageDefault",
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }
};
```

So here I am restricting use of **'Department/GetAllUsers'** which is working great. The problem arises when I split the string or assign the string to a variable. For example

```
var controller = "Department";
var action = "GetAllUsers";
$.ajax({
    url: "/" + controller + "/" + action,  
    //or '/Department/' + 'GetAllUsers'
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    success: function (result) {
        //Some Code
    },
    error: function () {
        //Some Code
    }
});
```

Here the restriction does not work, is there a way in which I can resolve the variable values at the url? Is this even possible using ESLint?

In short I want something like the context.SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(node) which is used in Roslyn for C# code analysis.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use ESLint's scope manager
https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/scope-manager-interface

There are many examples of using the scope manager in ESLint's own codebase:
https://github.com/eslint/eslint/search?q=getScope

Using this API you can follow the variable reference and inspect its assignments.

Note that this has some limitations. For example you won't be able to track values across module boundaries or function boundaries.

Comment: How exactly to inspect `var urls = { main: '/Department/GetAllUsers' };` ?